# Getting "error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source" while trying to load private nuget packages from Dockerfile

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-cli

I am trying to containerize a .net 6 application. It uses packages from nuget.org, as well as packages hosted under Artifacts in a 2019 Azure DevOps Server. I am getting **"error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source"** during the **dotnet restore in the Dockerfile** because for some reason it is not able to retrieve the packages from the DevOps Server.

Here is what the top of my Dockerfile looks like (The docker build fails during the dotnet restore operation):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]

COPY ../nuget.config .

RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj"
```

Here's is what the nuget.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="MyPrivatePackages" value="http://myazuredevopsserver/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyPrivatePackages/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <MyPrivatePackages>
            <add key="Username" value="unnecessary" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="myprivateaccesstoken" />
            <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
        </MyPrivatePackages>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

How can I resolve this error?

I have tried adding a proxy url in the nuget.config but it did not make a difference.

Comment: I had this problem today - in my case it turned out to be due to an outdated/expired token in the ClearTextPassword field. Might be worth double-checking